# Using polymer's `.job` in polymer.dart

Tags: dart, delay, jobs, dart-polymer

In Polymer there is a `this.job()` function that handles the [delayed processing of events](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#job). How do you access this functionality from polymer.dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    dom.window.onMouseMove.listen(mouseMoveHandler);
  }

  PolymerJob mouseMoveJob;
  void mouseMoveHandler(dom.MouseEvent e) {
    print('mousemove');
    mouseMoveJob = scheduleJob(mouseMoveJob, onDone, new Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  void onDone() {
    print('done');
  }
```

If the job isn't rescheduled for 500ms it is executed.
In polymer this is often used during initialization when

```dart
xxxChanged(old);
```

is called several times succinctly because `xxx` is updated on changes from several other states which are initialized one after the other but it is enough when `xxxChanged` is executed for the last update (a much shorter timeout should be used then like 0-20 ms depending whether `xxxChanged` is only called from sync or also from async code.

Another situation where I used this pattern (but not using `PolymerJob`) is where an `@observable` field is bound to a slider `<input type="range" value='{{slider}}'>`.
This invokes `sliderChanged(oldVal, newVal)` very often in a short interval when you move the knob. The execution of the update is expensive and can't be finished between two such calls see http://bwu-dart.github.io/bwu_datagrid/example/e04_model.html for an example.
Without some delayed execution this would be very cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Future`:

```
doJob() => print('hi');

new Future(doJob).then((_) => print('job is done'));
```

Here are the [docs for the Future class](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Future#id_Future-).

Comment: One of the things that I am interested in with the `.job` of Polymer is that it "can be called repeatedly before the timeout but it only results in a single side-effect." The future doesn't sound like it would be a very good match without a lot of extra code.

There is the [PolymerJob class](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/polymer/0.14.0+1/index.html#polymer/polymer.PolymerJob), but I'm still trying to figure out if that would work.